# Ruby filtering array of hash

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, hash, filter

I have the following array of arguments that has a hash with the args keys and their relevant passed values:

```
args_array = [{:collection=>["abe", "<mus>", "hest"], :include_blank=>true, :required=>true}]
```

I need to filter this hash to just get only some keys (like :include_blank and :required) in this example, with their relevant values like so:

```
filtered_args_hash = {:include_blank=>true, :required=>true}
```

So the `collection` arg is excluded, and just the `include_blank`, and `required` in which I specified are the ones returned.

**Update:**

Here is a keys array of symbols in which I need to filter according to them:

```
filter_keys = %i(include_blank required)
```

How I can do that?

Comment: Yes, keys = %i(include_blank required)

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use [`Hash#keep_if`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Hash.html#method-i-keep_if):

```
args_array[0].dup.keep_if {|k| filter_keys.include? k}
# => {:include_blank=>true, :required=>true}
```

<sub>Note that `.dup` is here to prevent `args_array` from being modified, don't use it if you do want `args_array` to be updated.</sub>

Comment: That modifies `args_array[0]` though. If I understand the question correctly, that behavior doesn't seem to be okay (maybe it is).  `Hash#select` can be used in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The following should do solve your problem:

```
 args_array.collect {|a| a if a[:include_blank] == true && a[:required=>true] == true }.compact
```

or

```
dup_list = args_array.dup
dup_list.delete_if {|a| !(a[:include_blank] == true && a[:required=>true] == true) }
```

Comment: But I need the include_blank and required returned with their values, whether they are true or false or whatever.

Comment: So you want to group them by include_blank and required ?

Answer (score 1):

```
args_array.map do |elem| 
  elem.select do |k, _| 
    %i(include_blank required).include? k
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You tagged as Rails so you can use [Hash#slice](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-slice):

```
args_array[0].slice *filter_keys
# => {:include_blank=>true, :required=>true}
```